# How to make Symfony2 return HTTP Response with Connection: Keep-Alive?

Tags: performance, http, rest, symfony, keep-alive

I'm using Symfony2 to create a REST API server for my application in the backend, and was thinking of reusing the same HTTP connection for subsequent queries using Http Keep-Alive, but after every query, I see a `Connection: close` in the response header.

Is there a way to tell Symfony2 to don't close the connection after each response and wait for more Request headers?

Comment: Have you tried to modify responce like `$response->headers->set('Connection', 'Keep-alive')`?

Comment: Yea, but I would have to set that individually for every response. Is there a way to do it globally?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems that the best solution is to write [kernel.response event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-response-event). And modify your request like `$response->headers->set('Connection', 'Keep-alive')`